# Referencing movieclip outside the DocumentClass

Tags: path, movieclip

I have this very simple ImageLoader class:

```
package 
{
    //
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    //
    public class ImageLoader extends MovieClip
    {
        var imageLoader:Loader;
        public function ImageLoader(img:String)
        {
            loadAsset(img);
        }
        //
        function loadAsset(url:String):void
        {
                    //warning here
            preloader.visible = true;
            imageLoader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imageLoading);
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
        }
        //;
        function imageLoaded(evt:Event):void
        {
                    //warning here
            imageLoaderClip.addChild(imageLoader);
            preloader.visible = false;
        }
        //
        function imageLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var loaded:Number = evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal;
            updateProgress(loaded);
        }
        //
        function updateProgress(value:Number)
        {
            preloader.progress.width = value * preloader.bar.width;
        }
    }
}
```

This work perfectly if this is the DocumentClass. 
BUT, if the DocumentClass is like this one:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class LoadTest extends MovieClip {

        public function LoadTest() {
            var img = new ImageLoader("DSC04550.JPG");
        }
    }
}
```

this doesn't work anymore, because of the presence of the stage movieclips "preloader" and "imageLoaderClip".

Which is the best way to make the things work? I thought to pass a reference to the ImageLoader class as a parameter. Is there any other (and better) way when dealing with situations like this one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out GreenSock's LoaderMax. It will make your project easier by an order of magnitude:

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

Comment: This is interesting, thanks, but I was looking for ways to deal with situations like the one I described (common practices and so on...)

Comment: From the looks of it, you have an instance of an object called "preloader" on your Stage. So when the document class is set to ImageLoader, the reference to preloader is automatically set. When you set the document class to LoadTest, your ImageLoader instance (img) no longer has a reference to preloader, plus you never add img to the display list.

Comment: The solution would either be to wrap the preloader object up as part of ImageLoader (so that it has a local reference to it) and add your ImageLoader instance to the display list, or pass a reference to the document's displaylist to its constructor. The former would be recommended.

Comment: Ok, I understood this before asking. I wanted to know which is a common way to work around this limitation (perhaps pass the two movieclip as parameters of ImageLoader? Pass stage?)

Comment: Generally speaking in object orientated programming, any given object should know as little as possible about its surroundings to maximize portability and minimize redundancy, in order to facilitate reuse. By that reasoning, you should instantiate a preloader display object within your image loader (since your image loader itself is a display object, contrary to its naming). Even if you do not use it, it's worth looking at the source for GreenSock's LoaderMax as this is a stellar example of a modular approach to asset loading and general code design.

Comment: Ok, I'll do what you suggest.

Comment: Last possible comment: I red a little the API and the samples (eg here: http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_loadermax.html) but as far as I can see, aside from various interesting functionalities, the "problem" would remain the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, after your further comments it became clear that your problem was due to the fact that you had items on the stage in Flash as well as class-based code. It is very easy to become confused when working like that (keeping track of objects instantiated via code, vs. dragged onto the timeline), which is why developers tend to prefer either one or the other for simplicity's sake.